# Диаграмма Ганта на web

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите, каким способом лучше сделать (скриншот) подобную диаграмму? Данные должны браться из базы данных и выводиться.
Видел примеры с использованием готовых скриптов, но нужно реализовать самописным кодом.
Буду благодарен за направление в сторону каких-то учебных материалов, библиотек.

Заранее благодарю.[image: Пример]

Comment: https://s-sd.ru/blog_studio_design/kalendar_sobytij_na_jquery/

Comment: Я бы предложил на svg нарисовать

Answer (score 0):

- Любым удобным для вас способом строите сетку дней.
- Оборачиваете ее в контейнер, относительно которого будете позиционировать линии диаграммы.
- Выгребаете данные из базы.
- Для каждой записи задаете в зависимости от значения ее полей цвет, заливку, иконку, надпись, пряжку, пуговицу, шнурок, хвост и гриву. Это будут свойства линий диаграммы.
- Из полей, в которых записана конечная и начальная даты, эти даты достаете и простыми арифметическими действиями переводите в проценты.
- Полученные проценты используете в качестве значений css-свойств `left` и `right` линий диаграммы.
- производите все остальные желаемые действия
- ?????
- ПРОФИТ: вы построили диаграмму Гантта на основе одного-единственного ответа на SO без того, чтобы проштудировать пару-тройку монографий на тему что это и как это сделать.

Удачи!